# iOS 11 MKAnnotationView prepareForReuse dismiss the pin view in Map view

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, view, mkannotationview

what I want to do is when I deselect an pin, the pin view change it's UI back to unselected state(e.g change color of background of the pin)

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
   //do something;

   XLMapItemAnnotation* mapItem = [self annotationForView:view];
   [view prepareForReuse];
}
```

by having this code,  when I run the app in iOS 11, if I deselect a pin, the pin disappear in the map view totally. and if I remove the prepareForReuse, everything would be fine. 
and the some code if I run the app in iOS 10, everything is fine, no pin get disappeared. 
can sbd give me a hint, what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not call `-prepareForReuse` yourself, it's intended for MapKit to call itself.

Answer (score 0):

As @Tim Johnsen said, `-prepareForReuse` is intended for MKAnnotationView's  reuse mechanism, you should not call it yourself.

In iOS 11, MapKit introduce clustering algorithm for MKAnnotationView(But after some try, I found it cause strange behavior sometimes). In this case, `MKAnnotationView.isHidden` is set as `true` by default. So after you invoking `-prepareForReuse`, MKAnnotationView is hidden.

If you want to change color of the pin, just change `pinTintColor` property directly, or use a function to reset all properties as needed.